# Обновление времени со старта JVM

Tags: java

Код, через который можно узнать время прошедшее со старта JVM таков:

```
long jvmUpTime = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getUptime();
```

Но в бекграунде он не обновляется, что и является вопросом. Просто заносится переменная и висит так до конца действия программы. Можно как-то сохранять значения по вызову?

Как его обновлять в приложении своём?

UPD:
Нашел решение

```
long jvmUpTime() { return ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getUptime(); }
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы получили значение в переменную и записали в адресное пространство текущий uptime, оно не должно обновляться.

Для того, чтобы получать uptime на текущий момент, необходимо сохранить **RuntimeMXBean** в отдельную переменную и каждый раз, когда необходимо, вызывать метод getUptime, тогда время будет соответствовать времени вызова.

Привожу пример подобной реализации:

```
RuntimeMXBean rb = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();

System.out.println("Up time: " + rb.getUptime() + " ms"); //Up time: 59 ms
Thread.sleep(1000 * 10);
System.out.println("Up time: " + rb.getUptime() + " ms"); //Up time: 10063 ms
```

Comment: вы серьезно? это из-за `Thread.sleep(1000 * 10);` он передает такие значения

Comment: @MatthewHaig Естественно! Ведь это я привел для примера, что данные в методе getUptime являются динамичными.